# Database for metric space search

Tags: database

I have a huge list of vectors (extracted from images, text, audio, whatever) and I want to do metric search. I want to input a query vector and retrieve the closest ones to it according to the euclidean distance. I know there are in-memory structures like the [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) but I was wondering if there is a Postgres-like software that could manage indexes larger than memory.

Comment: Geospatial databases do this, but generally with a restriction to 2- or 3-dimensional space, which probably won't suffice for your purpose.